# Twitter stream API returning 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm using the [Twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) Node module with Node.js to try to track certain hashtags for an app I'm writing and I'm not getting anything out of the Api other than an error saying "Error: Bad Twitter streaming request".  As far as I can tell I've followed the documentation but I'm obviously missing something.

Here is the code, with a few bits redacted:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

var http = require('http').createServer(app);
http.listen(80);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

var twitterApi = require('twit');

var twitter = new twitterApi({
    consumer_key: '***',
    consumer_secret: '***',
    app_only_auth: true
});

var stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: '#twitter'});
stream.on('tweet', function(tweet){
    console.log(tweet);
});
```

I'm working on an Ubuntu VM through Vagrant if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the API credentials right ? 401 is usually returned with a unauthorized request, so  I guess it must be with your API credentials.

Comment: Yeah I've double-checked the credentials for the application are correct.  I've seen in a few places that I have to connect via https, could that be it?

Comment: try curl with your api stream link and tell me if it works, I might have found your problem.

Comment: I've used https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator/ and done a test against https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json with track=twitter and it works fine

Comment: Is the Time in you Machine correct ? There is this known issue where the time stamp of local machine and server machine mismatches and the server throws a 401 error.

Comment: I've just taken out the "Access Token" and "Access Token Secret" from the signature generator and it's failing with a 401.  A bit closer at least.  I thought the app_only_auth: true would work?

Comment: yea,try adding the Access Token and the Secret to your Express Code, It might work.

Comment: Is it needed though?  Shouldn't it be possible to auth just the app rather than my user?  I saw something about a bearer token required for apps?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided access token and access token secret